# How to read/write data from an excel file using kotlin in jetpack compose for desktop

Tags: kotlin, desktop-application

How can I get/write data from a xlsx or xls file in a compose for desktop app using Kotlin ?
I've found [this link](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/excel-read-write) showing how to use it using Kotlin but I'm confused as to where do I put the below dependency code as I don't see any pom.xml file in my compose for desktop app project structure.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I know this question might come across silly but I'm totally new to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so if you use Compose Multiplatform Project - You probably using [Gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-gradle.html)

You have to find **build.gradle** (or build.gradle.kts ) file in the project root

And there you have to add dependencies in the corresponding section.

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3")
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3")
}
```

Take a look at few examples, or videos about Gradle because you gonna use it every day in your programming life)

Example screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had a build.gradle.kts file in the project src folder and I've pasted the code provided by you and tried to build the project but got errors `https://snipboard.io/xjMTn7.jpg`

Comment: @Bumba You have to add in under jvmMain package. 
Added screenshot